# What should I change in the following Kattis Tri exercise written in Python 3, so Kattis accepts it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I take user input while their input is less than 100 for all the numbers
Then if their input is valid I provide to go ahead and display all possible combinations with they entered numbers.
Here's the link for the exercise: https://open.kattis.com/problems/tri

I tried some text case ad the one that looks suspicious is division, so if I enter 3 2 1, then one of the outputs will be 3 / 2 = 1. Not sure if this is correct, everything else seems fine to me.

```
while True:
    var1, var2, var3 = input().split()
    if (int(var1) < 100 and int(var2) < 100 and int(var3) < 100):
        break;

if int(var1) == (int(var2)+int(var3)):
    print(int(var2),"+",int(var3),"=",int(var1))

if int(var2) == (int(var1)+int(var3)):
    print(int(var1),"+",int(var3),"=",int(var2))

if int(var3) == (int(var2)+int(var1)):
    print(int(var2),"+",int(var1),"=",int(var3))



if int(var1) == (int(var2)-int(var3)):
    print(int(var2),"-",int(var3),"=",int(var1))

elif int(var1) == (int(var3)-int(var2)):
    print(int(var3),"-",int(var2),"=",int(var1))

elif int(var2) == (int(var1)-int(var3)):
    print(int(var1),"-",int(var3),"=",int(var2))

elif int(var2) == (int(var3)-int(var1)):
    print(int(var3),"-",int(var1),"=",int(var2))

elif int(var3) == (int(var2)-int(var1)):
    print(int(var2),"-",int(var1),"=",int(var3))

elif int(var3) == (int(var1)-int(var2)):
    print(int(var1),"-",int(var2),"=",int(var3))


if int(var1) == (int(var2)/int(var3)):
    print(int(var2),"/",int(var3),"=",int(var1))

elif int(var1) == (int(var3)/int(var2)):
    print(int(var3),"/",int(var2),"=",int(var1))

elif int(var2) == (int(var1)/int(var3)):
    print(int(var1),"/",int(var3),"=",int(var2))

elif int(var2) == (int(var3)/int(var1)):
    print(int(var3),"/",int(var1),"=",int(var2))

elif int(var3) == (int(var1)/int(var2)):
    print(int(var1),"/",int(var2),"=",int(var3))

elif int(var3) == (int(var2)/int(var1)):
    print(int(var2),"/",int(var1),"=",int(var3))



if int(var1) == (int(var3)*int(var2)):
    print(int(var2),"*",int(var3),"=",int(var1))

elif int(var2) == (int(var1)*int(var3)):
    print(int(var1),"*",int(var3),"=",int(var2))

elif int(var3) == (int(var1)*int(var2)):
    print(int(var1),"*",int(var2),"=",int(var3))
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the things Blckknght mentioned:

There is just a single line of input. You could simply read it as:

```
var1, var2, var3 = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

According to the Output-Description your solution has be **in the same order** as the input, thus in the form:

```
var1 (op1) var2 (op2) var3
```

Since either op1 or op2 has to be the equal sign, you have just 8 cases to check.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is giving the wrong answer is some cases because you're using the wrong division operator. You're seeing `3/2=1` because you're using the `//` operator for the division tests. That does floor division, where `3 // 2` really is `1`. Use the regular `/` operator instead, since you don't want to detect a match when the integers don't divide evenly.

You probably also want to use `elif` statements, rather than just `if`s, since you need to only output a single solution for each input, rather than all of them.

Comment: Nope that didn't fix the problem. I think it has to do with the way I take in input